# UIBarButtonItem Highlighted Color

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have set a custom tint color for a `UINavigationBar` (within a `UINavigationController`) which, in turn, sets an appropriate matching color for the `UIBarButtonItems` which are inserted into the `UINavigationBar`. However, when I select a `UIBarButtonItem` the button turns into (presumably) the highlighted state and presents a different color, which looks quite a bit out and does not nicely match the tint color. Is there a way to change this highlighted state color to a custom color?

Ideally, I would like to just create a category on `UIBarButtonItem` which changes the highlighted color for all instances of `UIBarButtonItem`, as this would avoid the need to explicitly subclass `UIBarButtonItems` and then change every reference in my app to use the subclass (which will be tricky, as I am using some third-party libraries which just use `UIBarButtonItem` and I don't want to go messing with their implementation).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I remember from facing a similar issue, UINavigationBar will just take the tintColor and make it darker for the UIBarButtonItem (unless the style is set to BarStyleBlack, in which case it makes it a dull gray).

To do what you ask, I would create a custom UIButton with background images for the different control states that match your color scheme, then use this UIButton as the view for a custom UIBarButtonItem.

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:...];

//normal_button.png and selected_button.png need to be created by you
[customButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"normal_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customButton];
```

If you want to try and encapsulate this, you could always create a factory or a custom init method on UIBarButtonItem (via a category) and use the above code (with slight modifications).

I am aware that I am not fully addressing your second point on just overriding the control state with a category. I don't know what method to override in UIBarButtonItem to do such a thing, but you may be able to accomplish what you want via method swizzling (http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling) once you find out which method you want to exchange.

I should note that I've only ever used swizzling for testing/debugging.

Comment: How do you then set the selected state? UIBarButton.selected does not exist? How would you then access the UIButton inside UIBarButton?

Comment: The second image has to be set for UIControlState.Highlighted, not .Selected

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Interface Builder, drag and drop an UIButton to the navigation's bar right side, and it gets in as a right navigation bar button item. Then, configure different tints for different states of the button, and you're done.
Works in Xcode 10 and Swift 4.